# is it possible to store the codemirror6 EditorView into react state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Now I define the codemirror6 editor instance in react component like this:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { EditorState } from "@codemirror/state";
import { EditorView } from "@codemirror/view";

const App: React.FC = () => {

  const edContainer = useRef<any>();
  const [activeEditorView, setActiveEditorView] = useState<EditorView>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const state = EditorState.create({
      doc: "hello",
      extensions: [

      ]
    });
    const view = new EditorView({
      state,
      parent: edContainer.current,
    });
    setActiveEditorView(view);

    return () => {
      if (activeEditorView) {
        activeEditorView.destroy();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={edContainer}>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when I leave the component App, I want to destroy the code editor which stored in state. But now I found the activeEditorView always be undefined. Am I missing something? is it possible to store the EditorView in the state. I check the activeEditorView by add debugger command like this:

```
return () => {
      debugger
      if (activeEditorView) {
        activeEditorView.destroy();
      }
    };
```

Comment: How do you check the state of `activeEditorView`?

Comment: by add debugger command and then check it in google chrome dev tools.@kinduser